# how to get parameter data to DB:table query laravel

Tags: laravel

[image]

hi, i'm trying to show users data whereNotIn on other table using kelas_id.
but i cant use kelas_id params in query function on DB:table.
please help, thank you so much

Comment: Do not post the code as an image. No one can re-produce the code.

Comment: `function ($query) use ($kelas_id) { ... })` - Variable scopes; `$kelas_id` is not available inside of an anonymous function unless you explicitly allow it.

Comment: You are using a PHP Closure, when you need to pass variables that are outside the scope of that Closure, you need to add them with the `use` keyword. In this case: `whereNotIn('id', function ($query) use ($kalas_id) { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

i have found the answer,
u can solve this with add use ($diklat) after ($query)

the code will be like this :

```
$diklat = Diklat::where('id', $diklat_id)->first();
        $user = DB::table("users")->select('*')
                                  ->whereNotIn('id', 
                function ($query) use ($diklat) {
                          $query->select('user_id')
                                 ->from('diklat_details')
                                 ->where('diklat_id', $diklat->id);
                        })->where('users.role', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct, this is due to the scope of the variables. The anonymous function can't read the data $kelas_id because it's scopes begins when is created.
**The solution is a *use* and the variable we want to use**.

Comment: Hello, this answer would be better as a comment on the OP answer.  You can provide clarity in a comment to that answer.